# ¿Cómo hacer que Servicio de Windows se ejecute a horas predeterminadas?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, microsoft, windows-service

Tengo una aplicación la cual es un servicio de windows y necesito que se ejecute dos veces al día, la primera a las 3:00 AM y la segunda a las 8:00 PM

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Escribí este código y si no me equivoco creo que así puedo lograr que  se ejecute cada tres horas.

```
namespace MideToZettleService
{
    public partial class MideToZettle : ServiceBase
    {
        private Thread serviceThread;
        public MideToZettle()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            Temporizador.Interval = 10000;
            Temporizador.Start();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            this.serviceThread = null;
            Temporizador.Stop();
        }

        private void Temporizador_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Temporizador.Stop();

            this.serviceThread = new Thread(ServiceStart);
            this.serviceThread.Start();

            Temporizador.Interval = 10800000;
            Temporizador.Start();
        }

        private void ServiceStart()
        {
            //AQUI EL CODIGO QUE EJECUTO
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes crear un intervalo cada minuto ( 60,000 milisegundos) y verificar en tu `ServiceStart()` que hora es con `DateTime.Now`

Comment: Eso es en realidad lo que quiero evitar ... No puedo asegurar  que sea la hora exacta de esa forma

Comment: Misma pregunta en SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151363/windows-service-to-run-a-function-at-specified-time/19151658 tendrías que modificar  _timer.Interval en la segunda parte para guardar tus intervalos ( de 7 y  17 horas ) y utilizarlos alternadamente

Comment: Pregunta por si puedes cambiar en vez de un "servicio de windows" que es dificil de debugear, configurar, etc, ... ¿podrias crear una consola? Y dicha consola ejecutarla como [tarea programada en Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/about-the-task-scheduler)? Espero que puedas. sera mas sencillo todo (config, dev, debug, resolver problemas, deploy, etc)

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822